# OSError: [WinError 10038] Сделана попытка выполнить операцию на объекте, не являющемся сокетом

Tags: python

Возникла проблема при старте клиенской части (Пишу чат на сокетах)
Сервер стартует. На клиенте выдает ошибку:

```
/Desktop/Chat_Server/chat_client.py", line 26, in <module>
You can start scrip with parameters: script_name, IP address, port number
read_sockets, write_socket, error_socket = select.select(sockets_list, [], [])
OSError: [WinError 10038] Сделана попытка выполнить операцию на объекте, не являющемся сокетом
```

---

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

""" The chat client """

import sys
import select
import socket

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
COMMANDS = {'/h', '/l', '/x', '/u', '/t', }

if len(sys.argv) != 3:
    print("You can start scrip with parameters: script_name, IP address, port number")
    IP_address = '192.168.0.104'
    Port = 5050
else:
    IP_address = str(sys.argv[1])
    Port = int(sys.argv[2])

server.connect((IP_address, Port))
chat = True

while chat:
    sockets_list = [sys.stdin, server]
    read_sockets, write_socket, error_socket = select.select(sockets_list, [], [])

    for socket in read_sockets:
        if socket == server:
            message = socket.recv(2048).decode()
            if not message:  # server closed
                chat = False
                print('Server closed. Bye.')
                break
            sys.stdout.write(message)
            sys.stdout.write('\n ')
            sys.stdout.flush()
            if message.strip().startswith('Bye.'):
                chat = False
                break
        else:
            message = sys.stdin.readline()
            server.send(message.encode())
server.close()
```

Comment: Если мой ответ Вам помог, отметьте его, пожалуйста, как принятый нажатием на `v` под счётчиком голосов.

Answer (score 1):

Под Windows Вы не можете использовать `sys.stdin` с `select.select()`.

Выдержка из [документации](https://docs.python.org/3/library/select.html):

> `select.select(rlist, wlist, xlist[, timeout])`
>
> ...
>
> **Внимание:** Файловые объекты под Windows недопустимы, в отличие от сокетов. Под Windows функция `select()` обеспечивается библиотекой WinSock и не может работать с файловыми дескрипторами, созданными не в WinSock.

---

Одним из вариантов решения такой задачи может быть многопоточное приложение:

- Основной поток запускает дополнительные потоки. Один - ожидающий в цикле сообщений от stdin и другой - ожидающий сообщения из сокета;
- Оба дополнительных потока могут быть блокирующими;
- При получении сообщения, потоки передают его основному потоку через общую очередь;
- Основной поток в цикле ожидает сообщений из очереди - аналог `select.select`, и обрабатывает их

Comment: И даже нет аналогов ?

Comment: @NEOPLAY Одним из решений под Windows может быть многопоточное приложение. Я добавил в ответ общий алгоритм